# Visual Studio Code pane management like Origami

Tags: layout, window, visual-studio-code, pane

Has anyone found a way to have more complex pane layouts in Visual Studio Code, like those supported by [Origami for Sublime](https://github.com/SublimeText/Origami)? Layouts beyond splitting on the same axis are something that I really miss from Sublime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

like [@pat-putnam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7941225/pat-putnam) says, VSCode now supports editor window splitting

To replicate the Origami experience, we need the [Origami keyboard shortcuts](https://github.com/SublimeText/Origami#keyboard-shortcuts) too. To do this, paste the JSON snippet shown below into your VSCode `keybindings.json`.

You can quickly open `keybindings.json` in VSCode by pressing `cmd+shift+p` and then typing `keyb` and clicking the `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` completion hint that appears.

[image]

```
[
  {
    "key": "cmd+k up",
    "command": "workbench.action.splitEditorUp"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+k right",
    "command": "workbench.action.splitEditorRight"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+k down",
    "command": "workbench.action.splitEditorDown"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+k left",
    "command": "workbench.action.splitEditorLeft"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+k up",
    "command": "-workbench.action.moveActiveEditorGroupUp"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+k right",
    "command": "-workbench.action.moveActiveEditorGroupRight"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+k down",
    "command": "-workbench.action.moveActiveEditorGroupDown"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+k left",
    "command": "-workbench.action.moveActiveEditorGroupLeft"
  }
]
```

Note that if you have existing key bindings that you want to preserve, you should remove the `[` and `]` from the JSON snippet and just paste the config objects into your existing array.

These custom keybindings are for the editor-window-splitting functionality from Origami that I use most often. There are a few more [Origami keyboard shortcuts](https://github.com/SublimeText/Origami#keyboard-shortcuts) beyond these four.  It would be cool in the future to create a VSCode keybinding file that fully replicated the Origami keyboard shortcuts, and then release that as a VSCode keymap. Future work.

Comment: I hadn't considered adding some of the missing keybindings. These are fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

I recently revisited Visual Studio Code and found that you can now window split to your hearts content. Simply right click on any pane and select the appropriate split action.

[image]
[image]